# Cannot delete any entity during post operation of any phone call or appointment state change where auditing of the entity is turned on

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Imagine a scenario where a phone call or an appointment is being marked as complete.

I've set-up a plugin to fire during the post operation of both these scenarios in which I attempt to delete another unrelated record (using the Organization Service delete method). The record which I try to delete has auditing turned ON. The delete fails and I receive a business process error. If auditing is turned OFF, the process is successful. Does anyone have any insight as to what the problem might be?

Comment: Am I missing something here, or is this a non-programming question? I think this belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: @Polynomial It's programming - added c# tag

Comment: What's the specific programming problem? Please post the code that's failing.

Comment: @Polynomial Unfortunately it is work related so I haven't posted any code - the problem is very specific and I have tried to describe it as best I can. I feel the issue is configuration related regarding CRM and not specifically code related, as it only seems to fail in the specific scenario I have described

Comment: Instead of fighting for the correct place, invest your time and help to create it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2

Comment: Have you looked into the Trace yet?

Comment: @ckeller Haven't looked at tracing before... For the minute we have just disabled auditing on the entity and everything works perfectly. We will come back to look at the problem later, just hoping someone might have came across this before and save any more digging :)

Comment: Though I realise this question was asked almost a year ago, what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Just add a function to the "Mark as Complete" button, to delete whatever record you want.

Or create a custom button with this logic behind it.

Hope this helps.

Here is the code to delete a record through JavaScript

```
// Identify the contact to delete.
var contactid = "89a7e456-8098-bb33-b345-0003gg9ff218";
var authenticationHeader = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();
// Prepare the SOAP message.
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"+
" xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"+
" xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>"+
authenticationHeader+"<soap:Body>"+"<Deletexmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>"+
"<entityName>contact</entityName>"+
"<id>"+contactid+"</id>"+
"</Delete>"+"</soap:Body>"+"</soap:Envelope>";
// Prepare the xmlHttpObject and send the request,
var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Delete");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
xHReq.send(xml);
// Capture the result,
var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;
// Check for errors,
var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
if (errorCount != 0)
{
 var msg = resultXml.selectSingleNode('//description').nodeTypedValue;
 alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly isn't possible? Why would having auditing turned on have an effect on deleting a record and how would trying to delete it via a JavaScript function with ajax help?

Comment: Enabling auditing gives problems with deleting records by plugin. When you delete it through JavaScript it will not cause any conflicts. so write a function to delete the desired object in JavaScript, and add it to the mark complete button with the visual ribbon editor for example: http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why will using JavaScript avoid 'conflicts'? How is that different from other web service calls.

Comment: I have done researching on this matter but never found the problem. Using JavaScript solved my issue,  so I have no clue why this is any different from other webservice calls but it worked...